# How do I reduce the font size on tabs in Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, chromium

The tabs in Ubuntu (Xubuntu 14.04) have a larger font than Firefox. See comparison in attached image. How do I reduce this size?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Mint user ( using the same Ubuntu packages ) , I've found that everything was fine in Chromium up until 41.0.2272.76-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1076. Since then, the fonts in tabs, menus and bookmarks have grown by about 2pt as per the screenshots.

Chrome itself is still displaying correctly with the smaller font size. I have google-chrome-stable 41.0.2272.89-1 installed.

Comment: How is this an answer? I mean, how is this post a helpful answer?

Answer (score 5):

Click with the right button of mouse on the Chrome shortcut and "Properties".

Use this: 
**chromium-browser --force-device-scale-factor=0.5**

Now you can scale whatever you want, even bigger shit like factor=2
:D

Answer (score 4):

From here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GCd_JxQ33cU

> I found something of a workaround for my own system. You probably know
>   about your `~/.Xdefaults` file, Well, it turns out there  is a default
>   value that  helps. Modify the file, and reload using the command `xrdb
>   -load ~/.Xdefaults`. Then restart Chrome browser,  and, -- voila -- the tab font got larger. The lines I added are as follows:
>
> ```
> !! Xft settings help the problem with small font in google chromium tabs! 
> !! Xft.dpi: 96  is the setting that makes the tab font larger 
> Xft.dpi: 96 
> Xft.antialias: true 
> Xft.rgba: rgb 
> Xft.hinting: true 
> Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
> ```
>
> I found the above in a thread where people were talking about
>   improving the appearance of fonts in chrome on Linux, and discovered
>   that the 96dpi setting has the side-effect of increasing the font size
>   on the tabs. I should say that I am NOT a font expert, so I cannot
>   guarantee this will work on any system (possible depending on what
>   fonts you have installed?),  but I'd say it is quick and worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

For window managers that do not handle the font settings correctly, you can use your `~/.Xdefaults` file. Set `Xft.dpi` to e.g. `96`:

```
Xft.dpi: 96
```

And issue the command `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults`. Then restart your browser to see the effects of the settings. Tweak the `dpi` value until you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Install ubuntu unity tweak tool. 
In appearance secction click fonts and set font scaling factor according to your will.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you are expecting, but the [Ambiance Theme for Chrome (Maverick)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ambiance-theme-for-chrome/elnmibmpefhmfgphdphdncoogpbfmlbp?hl=en) adjusts the font to an acceptable size.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write somewhere like `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` something like this:

```
[Settings]
gtk-font-name=Noto Sans Regular 14
```